# I can connect to my tomcat6 server using http://localhost:8080/ but when I replace localhost with my ip address I'm unable to connect. What gives?

Tags: tomcat, localhost

Is there a configuration setting I need to modify somewhere for this to work?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Mac os x snow leopard.

Comment: do you have the firewall enabled? if so you need to add an exception for 8080

Comment: It wasn't the firewall it is turned off.  Apparently the firewalls on os x are off by default O.o

Answer (score 4):

Check you server configuration.

If the address var is set to 127.0.0.1 you wont be able to get to it via other addresses.

Change this to your IP address.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

Should be in conf/server.xml.

Also it may be that your app is restricted to certain hosts.

Check point 10 in this link:
http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html?page=2

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tomcat was returning a status 400. This was due to the fact that my tomcat installation did not have the following directory:
tomcat\webapps\ROOT

Inside this directory is the index.html that is being looked for when http://localhost:8081 is requested.

Just something else to check.